# String check with if js shorthand

Tags: javascript, shorthand-if

I have `var names = [];` and want push there some string only if it's not empty. Is there way make it with some shorthand method in js?)

That i have now.

```
 if ("" != opportunityName) 
    {
    names.push(opportunityName);
    }
```

And that Don't wotk for me, it's push empty string.

```
names.push(opportunityName || "");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use short-circuiting:

```
opportunityName && names.push(opportunityName);
```

The right-hand operand will only be evaluated if the left-hand one is truthy.

Comment: Thx, that was so simple =)

Comment: It works, but it's barely shorter than `if (opportunityName) names.push(...);` and less readable...

Comment: @LarsH It's shorter if curly braces are enforced by a code style, more so if new lines are added. I personally always use curly braces, so a short one-liner such as this is sometimes just what I need.

Comment: @timenomad: A valid point, in practice... such coding styles are not uncommon. I would say, though, that if a coding style enforces curly braces for the "then" clause of `if`, then in order to be consistent, it should enforce parentheses around the right-hand expression in this pattern where `&&` is used only for short-circuiting: `opportunityName && (names.push(opportunityName))`. However I haven't seen coding styles that enforce the latter.